# Android OpenGL set rotation speed of cube

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I have cube that rotates around the center of the coordinates system. But the problem is it rotates very slowly. So in my case how to set the rotation speed?

The following three methods update the mCurrentModelMatrix with the given model transformation. These are stateful accumulative methods.

```
    public void trnslate(float x, float y, float z)
    {
       float[] tempModelMatrix = new float[16];       
       Matrix.setIdentityM(tempModelMatrix, 0);
       Matrix.translateM(tempModelMatrix,0,x,y,z);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(this.mCurrentModelMatrix, 0, 
              tempModelMatrix, 0, this.mCurrentModelMatrix, 0);
    }
    public void rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z)
    {
       float[] tempModelMatrix = new float[16];       
       Matrix.setIdentityM(tempModelMatrix, 0);
       Matrix.rotateM(tempModelMatrix,0,angle,x,y,z);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(this.mCurrentModelMatrix, 0, 
              tempModelMatrix, 0, this.mCurrentModelMatrix, 0);
    }
    public void scale(float xFactor, float yFactor, float zFactor)
    {
       float[] tempModelMatrix = new float[16];       
       Matrix.setIdentityM(tempModelMatrix, 0);
       Matrix.scaleM(tempModelMatrix,0,xFactor,yFactor,zFactor);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(this.mCurrentModelMatrix, 0, 
              tempModelMatrix, 0, this.mCurrentModelMatrix, 0);
    }

    /*
     * Calculaute the final model view matrix
     * 1. Order of matrix multiplication is important
     * 2. MVPmatrix = proj * view * model;
     * 3. Setup the MVP matrix in the vertex shader memory
     */
    protected void setupMatrices()
    {
       float[] tempModelMatrix = new float[16];
       Matrix.setIdentityM(tempModelMatrix, 0);

        //translate the model combo next
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, //matrix and offset 
              mCurrentModelMatrix, 0, 
              tempModelMatrix, 0);

       //translate eye coordinates first
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, 
              this.mVMatrix, 0, 
              mMVPMatrix, 0);

        //Project it: screen coordinates
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, 
              mProjMatrix, 0, 
              mMVPMatrix, 0);

        //Set the vertex uniform handler representing the MVP matrix
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, //uniform handle 
              1, //number of uniforms. 1 if it is not an array
              false, //transpose: must be false
              mMVPMatrix, //client matrix memory pointer
              0); //offset
    }
```

**draw method**

```
   // Drawing operation
@Override
protected void draw(GL10 gl, int positionHandle) {
    // Hide the hidden surfaces using these APIs
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LESS);

    // Transfer vertices to the shader
    transferVertexPoints(positionHandle);
    // Transfer texture points to the shader
    transferTexturePoints(getTextureHandle());

    // Implement rotation from 0 to 360 degrees
    // Stop when asked and restart when the stopFlag
    // is set to false.
    // Decide what the current angle to apply
    // for rotation is.
    if (stopFlag == true) {
        // stop rotation
        curAngle = stoppedAtAngle;
    } else {
        curAngle += 1.0f;
    }
    if (curAngle > 360) {
        curAngle = 0;
    }

    // Tell the base class to start their
    // matrices to unit matrices.
    this.initializeMatrices();

    // The order of these model transformations matter
    // Each model transformation is specified with
    // respect to the last one, and not the very first.

    // Center the cube
    this.trnslate(0, 0, -1);
    // Rotate it around y axis
    this.rotate(curAngle, 0, -1, 0);
    // Decenter it to where ever you want
    this.trnslate(0, -2, 2);

    // Go ahead calculate the ModelViewMatrix as
    // we are done with ALL of our model transformations
    this.setupMatrices();

    // Call glDrawArrays to use the vertices and draw
    int vertexCount = mTriangleVerticesData.length / 3;
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, // what primitives to use
            0, // at what point to start
            vertexCount); // Starting there how many points to use
    // Check if there are errors
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rotating at 1 degree per frame, so it will take 360 frames to do a complete rotation.

If you want it to rotate in 2 seconds, and you were running at 30 frames per second, you would want to rotate by 6 degrees per frame, by changing this section:

```
if (stopFlag == true) {
    // stop rotation
    curAngle = stoppedAtAngle;
} else {
    curAngle += 6.0f;
}
if (curAngle > 360) {
    curAngle = 0;
}
```